# ADT key-concepts for implementing a hash table

Tags: data-structures, hash, implementation

I need some advice for implementing a good hash table structure. I've researching something, but I would like some external opinions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever hash function you choose you have to fullfil the following requirements:

- provide a uniform distribution of hash values: a non-uniform distribution will increase the amount of collisions between mapped values.
- good schema for collision resolution: it's almost impossible to avoid them, so you will have to implement some strategies such as "separate chaining" or "open addressing". A good starting point is http://task3.cc/44/hash-maps-with-linear-probing-and-separate-chaining/.